# How to show the confirmation alert with one button using javascript?

Tags: javascript

In my application, i need to show the message in alert with OK button.

In that button click event, i want to do some functionalities using the javascript.

So, how can i do this in my app?

Please let me know?

Comment: What's the point of a confirmation alert with only one button? If the user only has one option anyway, it behaves exactly like there was no button, except that it makes the user have to perform some silly clicking task. Are you sure you don't want an OK/Cancel dialog?

Answer (score 9):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but you may be looking for the [`window.confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.confirm) function, which is a built-in function like `alert` that allows you to capture the response (true or false) from the user:

```
if(confirm("Some message")) {
    //Clicked ok
} else {
    //Clicked cancel
}
```

If you want more functionality than that I'm afraid you'll have to look elsewhere. There are endless modal scripts and libraries available, so just search for one that suits your needs.

---

Having re-read your question title, maybe you just want the normal [`window.alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.alert) function? That will display a dialog with one button, and, in general, prevent execution of the code following it until the user has closed it:

```
alert("Some message");
```

Answer (score 3):

If you'll be using alert() then the execution of javascript will stop where the alert is written. And after the OK button is pressed, the code execution will resume.
So, do an alert(message); and after that line, put the code you want to be executed after the OK button is pressed.

If you want more control, you can use jQuery UI Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about built-in popups. Even if you make it work you'll probably hit some cross-browser issues and you won't be able to sleep (trust me: I know what I'm saying, I've been there). :)

I've been using jQuery UI ( [link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation) ) for some time and I am really satisfied with. Give it a try!

Comment: Im a huge fan of jQuery ... but adding the jQuery library and the UI library just for a simple confirm message .... really ?

Comment: Javascript `confirm` is cross-browser and has been supported by every major browser since the late 1990s.

Comment: @ManseUK: why not? Good pagaes nowadays have to use JavaScript anyway, it will come handy in the future.

Comment: yeah, using jquery for a simple confirm is not good unless you want to customize the confirm box & js `confirm` is cross-browser already..

Comment: @PeterOlson Yeah, it is. But it is so raw and ugly, you can't customize it. You can't add some custom functonalities, etc.

Comment: ^In the above question, the asker hasn't mentioned about customization.

Comment: @gopi1410 Of course. But I thought it will be a good idea to guide him a little bit. ;) It is always a good idea to talk about other possibilites. Maybe asker will find it more useful then a pure answer to the question.

Comment: @freakish I also think jQuery would be a huge bloat here. Future might-be-useful optimization is calling for misery.

Comment: @RomainVALERI This is a matter of opinion. But it really is hard for me to believe that someone actually believes that jQuery is an overkill in any situation. :) Well, my opinion is that it is fine even if used for one simple task.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example

```
if (confirm("Select a button")){
    alert("You selected OK");
}else{
    alert("You selected Cancel");
}
```

But if you're just looking for a popup with one button I would go for the `alert()`

```
alert("Press OK to close!");
```

[For more popup examples, go to w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp)